# Case Switch with a loop

Tags: c#, loops

I am not understanding what is going on in my case statement to determine if I want to redo the users input. Should I make another loop outside of my while loop? I attempted such and my case statement becomes unreachable code. Maybe I am not understanding case-switch statements.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string _a = "";
        constructor con = new constructor();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter enter exit to end the program...");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter C for constructor, M for method, A for an array...");
        Console.WriteLine("Please reference source code to have full details and understanding...");
        bool control = true;
        while (control)
        {
            _a = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (_a.ToUpper())
            {

                case "EXIT":
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using AJ's program...");
                    control = false;
                    break;
                case "C":
                    Console.WriteLine(con.a);
                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to test another scenario?");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    if (_a.ToUpper() == "Y")
                    {
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        return;

                    }
                    control = false;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    control = false;
                    metroid();
                    break;
                case "A":
                    control = false;
                    Array();
                    break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("No match");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public class constructor
    {
        public string a = "This is a constructor!";
    }
    static public void metroid()
    {
        string b = "This is a method!";
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
    static public void Array()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a random array. Please enter the size.");
            string sSize = Console.ReadLine();
            int arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(sSize);
            int[] size = new int[arraySize];
            Random rd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                size[i] = rd.Next(arraySize);
                Console.WriteLine(size[i].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not correct format, restarting array process.");
            Array();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you simply want to the instructions to be seen again, move the `Console.Write` statements into the `while` loop.

Comment: @paqogomez all of them?????

Comment: @paqogomez The instructions with arguments enacted doesn't work...

Comment: Tell me what you mean by "redo the user input"?

Comment: @paqogomez if they enter Y I want it to go back to the main method

Comment: So you want the app to never end?  How does the user get out?

Comment: No No No. @paqogomez enter Exit will break it. any other key responds. Its when you select a specific, such as C or M or A, it prompts you if you want to loop again or not.

Comment: `Return` will end the program(exit the main method), `continue` will skip straight to the top of the loop again (continuing the loop), `break` will exit the loop and continue the method.  `control = false` will also end the loop after it gets through one cycle.

Comment: Ah, then your problem is in your `ReadLine` after you test for "Y".  You dont capture that variable, so return closes the app. The other thing that will finish the loop is both the `control = false` and the `break`

Comment: @paqogomez continue would take it back to the default wouldn't it. I am going to test this. Maybe you can do the same? Im looking at this and trying to figure it out on paper.

Comment: Check my answer, I think i've got your main function figured out.  Let me know if it doesnt perform as expected.

Comment: I did make one misstatement, the `break`s that you use only break out of the switch, not the loop.  A `break` can also be used to break out of a loop, but you'd have to be outside the switch first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with.  You had too many ways of exiting your loop, so I removed all of the `control = false` lines except where the user typed "EXIT"

Also, in case "C" you return out of the method if they choose "Y", I changed that to `continue` so that the loop would continue.

Finally, I moved the 3 instruction statements into the loop, so when the user hit "Y" it would print those again.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string _a = "";
    constructor con = new constructor();
    bool control = true;
    while (control)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter enter exit to end the program...");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter C for constructor, M for method, A for an array...");
        Console.WriteLine("Please reference source code to have full details and understanding...");
        _a = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (_a.ToUpper())
        {

            case "EXIT":
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using AJ's program...");
                control = false;
                break;
            case "C":
                Console.WriteLine(con.a);
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to test another scenario?");
                _a = Console.ReadLine(); //<==problem #1 you didnt set your var name
                if (_a.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                    continue; //<==problem #2 return exits the program, continue, just keeps going
                }
                control = false;
                break;
            case "M":
                metroid();
                break;
            case "A":
                Array();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("No match");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you want to change

```
                Console.ReadLine();
                if (_a.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;

                }
```

as

```
                _a = Console.ReadLine();
                if (_a.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                    _a = Console.ReadLine();
                    continue;

                }
```

Comment: Without testing that I am going to assume it will cycle through and end the program

Answer (score 0):

I think you should considering `goto` in this case. Yes you need to put some extra effort, but it will help you overcoming the `While` loop.

A sample below:

```
 switch (_a.ToUpper())
  {
    case "EXIT":
      Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using AJ's program...");
      control = false;
      // execute goto when your all line executes successfully
      goto case "New";

     case "New":
     // some logic
  }
```

See working sample here [Goto-Switch](http://www.dotnetperls.com/goto-switch)

Comment: Oh please tell me you did not just recommend a goto.

Answer (score 0):

```
                string NewInput= Console.ReadLine();
                if (NewInput.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                   //print some thing with console.writeline

                   //if after this you want to restart the loop then instead of return use 
                   continue;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Console.Writeline inside the while loop like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool control = true;
    while (control)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter enter exit to end the program...");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter C for constructor, M for method, A for an array...");
        Console.WriteLine("Please reference source code to have full details and understanding...");
        string _a = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (_a.ToUpper())
        {
            case "EXIT":
                Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using AJ's program...");
                control = false;
                break;
            case "C":
                Console.WriteLine("press c");
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to test another scenario?");
                Console.ReadLine();
                if (_a.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;

                }
                control = false;
                break;
            case "M":
                control = false;
                metroid();
                break;
            case "A":
                control = false;
                Array();
                break;
            default: Console.WriteLine("No match");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Additional reading about switch [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch).

Just add comment for the result, thanks. Hope this helped!

Comment: it compiles but ends after I input Y

Comment: You should not set control to false in case "C"